# Set inclusion between convex polytopes with $\mathcal{H}$-representation

Tags: convex-analysis, polyhedra, polytopes, discrete-geometry, decision-problems

Let $\mathcal{P}_1$ and $\mathcal{P}_2$ be two convex polytopes with $\mathcal{H}$-representation, i.e.,

\begin{align}
\mathcal{P}_1 &= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n\colon A_1x \leq b_1\},\\
\mathcal{P}_2 &= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n\colon A_2x \leq b_2\},
\end{align}

where $A_1, A_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $b_1,b_2 \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Then, how to judge if $\mathcal{P}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{P}_2$? (Can I convert this problem into an optimization problem?) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\mathcal{P}_1$ happens to be bounded, then the set $\mathcal{V}_1$ of its vertices would be finite. Thus you just would have to check $x_k\in\mathcal{P}_2$ for each $x_k\in\mathcal{V}_1$.

I.e. you don't need any optimization here. But you'd need to convert the $\mathcal{H}$-representation of $\mathcal{P}_1$ into a corresponding $\mathcal{V}$-representation.

--- rk

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer [+1]. It is NP-hard to convert one representation to the other. Is it possible to remove the redundant constraints in $\mathcal{P}_1 \bigcap \mathcal{P}_2$ with low complexity and see if this intersection has the same $\mathcal{H}$-representation to $\mathcal{P}_2$? (If so, this method can be applied to polyhedra as well.)

Comment: @Ryan: If 2 bounding hyperplanes are parallel, the farer one clearly can be omitted. But in general you would have to evaluate whether each bounding hyperplane of $\mathcal{P}_2$ is redundant for $\mathcal{P}_1$ or not. And this is nothing but one part of your original quest each.

Comment: Good observation! I think I can still use your method to handle polyhedra. Without loss of generality, we assume $\mathcal{P}_2$ is unbounded. Then, there exists a coordinate transformation $\bar{x} = Q x$ such that $A_2 Q^{-1} = [\bar{A}_2 0]$, which projects $\mathcal{P}_2$ to a subspace and the projection $\bar{\mathcal{P}}_2$ is a polytope. Now, we can apply the same transformation to $\mathcal{P}_1$: i) if $\bar{\mathcal{P}}_1$ is unbounded, $\mathcal{P}_1 \not\subseteq \mathcal{P}_2$; ii) otherwise, use your method to check the inclusion.