# How to determine whether a given convex polytope is contained in another given convex polytope?

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, polytopes, discrete-geometry, decision-problems

Given a tall matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ (where $m > n$) and a vector $b\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$, we say that they define the set $$\mathcal{S} = \left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: Ax\le b\right\}$$ where the inequality is element-wise. We may also assume that this set is bounded. Suppose that I am given two pairs, $(A_1, b_1)$ and $(A_2, b_2)$. How can I check whether the set $\mathcal{S}_2$ is a subset of $\mathcal{S}_1$?

If it helps, we may assume that both $A_1$ and $A_2$ are lower triangular.

Comment: $S$ is never bounded. If $A=0$, then any vector is in $S$, and if $A\neq 0$, then its range is at least one-dimensional, hence contains vectors of arbitrarily large coordinates.  So you may want to modify your assumption.

Comment: @uniquesolution sorry, $A$ is not square. We have more inequalities than variables.

Comment: Apparently this is the same question as here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3524141/set-inclusion-between-convex-polytopes-with-mathcalh-representation

Comment: Also relevant, 3 other questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513513/polytopes-inside-polytopes?, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343280/how-to-check-whether-a-convex-polyhedron-is-contained-in-another-convex-polyhedr/1344131, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097171/is-it-possible-to-check-polytope-containment-by-only-checking-the-feasibility-of

Answer (score 1):

> 4. POLYTOPE CONTAINMENT 
>     **Input:** Polytope $P$ given in $\mathcal H$-description, polytope $Q$ given in $\mathcal V$-description 
>     **Output:** "Yes" if $P \subseteq Q$, "No" otherwise 
>     **Status (general):** co$\mathcal NP$-complete 
>     **Status (fixed dim.):** Polynomial time 
>     Freund and Orlin [20] proved that this problem is co$\mathcal NP$-complete. Note that the reverse question whether $Q \subseteq P$ is trivial. The questions where either both $P$ and $Q$ are given in $\mathcal H$-description or both in $\mathcal V$-description can be solved by linear programming (Problem 1), see Eaves and Freund [17]. For fixed dimension, one can enumerate all vertices of $\mathcal P$ in polynomial time (see Problem 1) and compare the descriptions of $P$ and $Q$ (after removing redundant points).

---

<sub>**Source:** Volker Kaibel, Marc E. Pfetsch, [Some algorithmic problems in polytope theory](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.math/0202204), 2002.</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to [17]. Do you know what the LP formulation of my problem is?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA090471.pdf) technical report.

Comment: Just to help readers unfamiliar with the vocabulary of polytopes: *"A representation of a polytope by a set of inequalities, is an H-representation. On the other hand, when a polytope is given a convex hull of a set of points we have a V-representation."* (from De Loera's ["ACTUALLY DOING IT"](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~deloera/TEACHING/MATH114/justdoit.pdf) lecture notes). So the question falls in the category "both P and Q are given in H-description" for which reference "[17]" (Eaves &  Freund, 1982 https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01583784) in indeed relevant.

Comment: Perhaps I have read (Eaves & Freund, 1982) too fast, but I believe the solution given at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2097261/289775 is the same as the Farka's lemma proposed in the Eaves & Freund paper.